# Can you set a stored procedures parameters from the output of a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that generates a list of product sequence numbers.

```
exec GenerateSequenceList @Min = 10, @Max = 25, @Prefix = N'Toaster'
```

I have to now generate a list of sequences for a report.
Is there a way I can feed this stored procedure from the output of a query?
For example generate a sequence list for all toasters, ladles and pans.

```
select min, max, prefix from products where prefix in ('Toaster', 'Ladle', 'Pan')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a loop, yes. Once per row and you'd have multiple resultsets (one stored proc output repeated per loop iteration

The best way is using [APPLY](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-apply-basics/) and udfs if you can re-write to use UDFs

```
select P.prefix , T.* 
from 
   products P
   CROSS APPLY -- or OUTER APPLY maybe
   dbo.SomeUDF (P.min, P.max, P.prefix) T
where 
   P.prefix in ('Toaster', 'Ladle', 'Pan')
```

The udf can be called in the stored procedure of course to maintain the "API"

Comment: +1 : If logic is read-only, encapsulating it in a table valued user defined function gives you much much more flexibility.